# Download Excel file as a response from Open Api 3

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I am editing in editor.swagger.io
How can I download response from API locally which is a excel file? The API being used for converting json to Excel is written in python.
My snippet -

```
responses:
        200:
          description: "JSON to Excel conversion succeeded"
          content:
            application/vnd.ms-excel:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
```

I get server response of 200 saying

> Could not render this component, see the console.

In console the response headers are -

> cache-control: public, max-age=0
>
> content-length: 8515
>
> content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
>
> expires: Tue, 10 Dec 2019 15:14:55 GMT

I want to save excel file locally.

Comment: Your response definition is correct. Is there a specific problem you have with using it?

Comment: I am doing a post request to an endpoint and passing json to it. It returns a file in excel format. I want to save it locally in my PC. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the current behavior and how is it different from the expected behavior?

Comment: It is not able to render the component and in console I get the response headers but I want to save the attachment or file locally.

Comment: @Helen I have edited the question to show what I am getting in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that Content Disposition header has to be exposed in the python code for MIME types such as application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.

In python code you should have a line like this -

```
CORS(app,expose_headers=["Content-Disposition"])
```

If your MIME type is application/octet-stream then this isn't required but for other MIME types this may be required.